# Elasticsearch 2.0 scripting: Invoke custom script from plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, aggregation

If we defined native script in plugin: com.test.nativescript.TestScript, can we invoke that package inside another groovy script and create new instance ?

Ex: 
inside config/scripts/test.groovy:

```
import  com.test.nativescript.TestScript;

def testScript = new TestScript()
```

Result:

> "startup failed:\r\nc78a82bc96ca7751e83e256b4ee0c322cda13bea: 1:
>   unable to resolve com.test.nativescript.TestScript"

Comment: Can someone help me pls. I really need answer.